# React Native - Check if Bluetooth is turned on, and if not alert the user?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

There is a way to check if the Bluetooth is turned on and if not, then alert the user? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Installation: `npm install react-native-bluetooth-status --save`

Link this plugin: `react-native link react-native-bluetooth-status`

import: `import { BluetoothStatus } from 'react-native-bluetooth-status';`

Check Bluetooth turn on or turn off code :

BluetoothStatus.state() is return boolean . if return true the bluetooth is **ON** if return false the bluetooth is **OFF**

```
componentDidMount() 
{
   this.checkInitialBluetoothState();
}

async checkInitialBluetoothState() 
{
const isEnabled = await BluetoothStatus.state();
console.log("check bluetooth on or off", isEnabled);
if(isEnabled == true){
  Alert.alert(
      'Bluethooth',
      'Bluetooth is turn on'
    );
 } else{
    Alert.alert(
      'Bluethooth',
      'Bluetooth is turn off'
    );
  }
}
```

[react-native bluetooth status](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-status)

Comment: Unfortunately with this approach I am receiving "false" all the time, event when Bluetooth is switched on in general settings and app settings.

Comment: @GrzegorzPawlik did you react-native-bluetooth-status link properly

Comment: yes I did link it just like indicated in the documentation

Comment: On RN 0.60+ with autolinking you want to run pod install in your ios/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create your own BT module and import it as a component.

The Native module will have to include the

`#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>`

to check the status of the BT.

```
// This delegate will monitor for any changes in bluetooth state 

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

    NSString *stateString = nil;
    switch(_bluetoothManager.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."; break;
        default: stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; break;
    }
  //stateString
  //do the react native thing and send the stateStringback or w/e you want. Maybe send an alert.
}
```

That's the jist of it. I'm not going to go through how to create a native component there are plenty of tutorials online.

Or when the state changes you can call the `UIAlertView` delegate, this delegate will allow you to send the alert to the user.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into to it!